# codeigniter email class not sending mail with imap

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, imap

I'm trying to send mail with ***IMAP*** ***connection***.
For Connecting, I'm using this libraries:

> http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-661.html

Here is my code:

```
$config['protocol'] = "imap";
$config['imap_host'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$config['imap_user'] = 'user@domain.com';
$config['imap_pass'] = 'Jk98S**Jlk';
$config['imap_port'] = '993';
$config['imap_path'] = '/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert';
$config['imap_server_encoding'] = 'utf-8';
$config['imap_attachemnt_dir'] = './tmp/';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from($mailfrom, $fromname);
$this->email->to($tomail);
$this->email->reply_to($mailfrom, $fromname;
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

With this settings I'm connecting to server and reading and deleting mails
but when I try to send mail it's returning this message:

> Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.

what is wrong?
why it's using *PHP mail()*?
as I know it must use `imap_connect` and send mail with it.

I would like to ask you for any kind of help.

Comment: IMAP isn't meant for *sending*, but receiving mails.

Comment: as I know IMAP can send mail so good as reading mail... so why not???

Comment: I do not understand how but now it is working. I changed nothing but it is working thank you...